# How to get commit after N commits from tag?

Tags: git

For example, I have a next tag - `2.0.0`

I want to know hash id commit after N commits from this tag.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean "N" commits after the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the children by using `git log --reverse`.

To get the 5th commit north of tag 2.0.0:

```
git log --reverse -n5 2.0.0 --pretty="%H" | head -n1
```

NOTE: If there are less than 5 commits north of commit you will get the most recent.

Comment: Thank you for solution! But, can I get this only via git command? I need in crossplatform solution

Comment: The only part that isn't cross platform is the `|head n1`. The most recent commit will be the top line. Git bash may have the `head` command. If not Cygwin def has it. EDIT: Looks like windows would be `-HEAD 1` or `-First 1`